# Vue.js rerender array item correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got an array in `vue.js` 2 with this structure:

```
data() {
    return {
        ports: [
            { id: 1, name: "example", "age": 10, scores: [ {index: 1, value: 100}, {index: 2, value: 200} ]},
            { id: 2, name: "example", "age": 10, scores: [ {index: 1, value: 100}, {index: 2, value: 200} ]}
            { id: 3, name: "example", "age": 10, scores: [ {index: 1, value: 100}, {index: 2, value: 200} ]}
            { id: 4, name: "example", "age": 10, scores: [ {index: 1, value: 100}, {index: 2, value: 200} ]}
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to replace the `scores` of `port` with id `1`. I know I can replace the entire port like this:

```
Vue.set(this.ports, 0, newPort);
```

But then `scores` on the `port` object is not `reactive` anymore and it does not `rerender` in my subcomponents!

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: does changing another data after replacing scores work?

Comment: That's the problem. Right now I change the entire port and then scores is not reactive. I only need to change the scores!

Comment: i dont think it's possible for vue to detect changes in array right now, you could add another data and change that every time you replace something in the array.

Comment: Hmm how would that look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But then scores on the port object is not reactive anymore and it does not rerender in my subcomponents!

The `scores` property will be reactive provided that it exists on the `newPort` object at the time of the `Vue.set` call.

> I want to replace the scores of port with id 1.

Why are you replacing the entire port object instead of just the scores? This will work:

```
this.ports.find(port => port.id === 1).scores = newScores
```